# In C++, why is `new` needed to dynamically create an object rather just allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, alignment, new-operator

I've got this trivial class hierarchy:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual int x( ) const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int _x;
public:
    Derived( int x ) : _x(x) { }
    int x( ) const { return _x; }
};
```

If I use `malloc` to allocate an instance of `Derived`, and then try to access the polymorphic function `x`, program crashes (I get a segmentation fault):

```
int main( ) {
    Derived *d;
    d = (Derived*) malloc( sizeof(Derived) );
    *d = Derived( 123 );

    std::cout << d->x() << std::endl; // crash

    return 0;
}
```

Of course my actual application is a lot more complex (it's a sort of memory pool).

---

I'm pretty sure it's because of the way I allocate `d`: I didn't use `new`.

I know of [placement `new`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) operator, which must be what I need, but I've never used it and have got some questions:

- why is my application crashing, if I don't use `new`?

  What does `new` actually do?

  Why can't I just use the assignment operator to assign the value of `Derived( 123 );` to the memory area pointed by `d`?
- Would I need to use `new` also for non-polymorphic types?

  How about POD ones?
- On the [C++Faq I linked above](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) it says that the memory region passed to placement `new` must be aligned for the object I'm creating.

  I know what alignment is, but I don't know how to check the alignment needed for my class.

  `malloc` manual says:

  > The  malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable.

  And I hope that the alignment needed for my class is the class size as returned by `sizeof`, so that any address in the form `address_returned_by_malloc + i * sizeof(my_class)` is suitable to allocate my objects.

  Are my hopes right?

Comment: Why don't you just override the new operator for this class?

Comment: "Why isn't `malloc` working for classes?" and "Why do we need `new`?" are very different questions, one of which has an answer.

Comment: @Earlz, I'm over**loading** new operator, but I wanted to know why I had to use `new`. @Chris Lutz: yes and no; this question was: "Why do I need to use `new` instead of `malloc` to instantiate class objects?"

Comment: @Chris: They both have answers: "Because the object's lifetime hasn't started, so you can't use it" and "Because it's the only way to initialize a dynamically allocated object" respectively.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I think, on a more conceptual levep, adding `new` as an operator (instead of e.g. a template function) was a mistake. The same functionality could have been achieved without such drastic (and difficult to extend) changes to the language.

Comment: @Chris: Syntax for calling a constructor needs language support.  There's no way to implement a library function without it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Yes, but it doesn't need to be inseparably mixed with memory allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go down the line

1. why is my application crashing, if I don't use new?

Virtual table is corrupted.

The virtual table is stuck right after the allocated memory.  when you `new` a class, the generated code will properly set up the vtable.  However, malloc will not properly initialize the vtable

To see the virtual table, run
    g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy

```
Vtable for Derived
Derived::_ZTV7Derived: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI7Derived)
16    Derived::x

Class Derived
   size=16 align=8
   base size=12 base align=8
Derived (0x10209fc40) 0
    vptr=((& Derived::_ZTV7Derived) + 16u) <-- notice how this is part of the structure
  Base (0x10209fcb0) 0 nearly-empty
      primary-for Derived (0x10209fc40)
```

For a similar reason, without overloading operator=, the generated assembly code will only copy the data and not the vtable [again, the compiler only knows to copy the data, not the vtable]

If you want to see a pointer-based version with a valid vtable function:

```
Derived e(123);
d = &e;
```

1. Would I need to use new also for non-polymorphic types?

If you are using virtual functions, then yes, even for non-polymorphic types

1. I hope that the alignment needed for my class is the class size as returned by sizeof, so that any address in the form address_returned_by_malloc + i * sizeof(my_class) is suitable to allocate my objects.

Alignment is not an issue.

Comment: Sizeof does not skip the vtable size. The vtable size is included in the sizeof, no problem. the problem is simply that malloc does not initialize the vtable (or anything else). Had the OP used placement new on the malloc'd data, no problem

Comment: "if you are using virtual functions, then yes, even for polymorphic types" is also utter nonsense.  The very definition of a polymorphic type is a class type with virtual functions.

Comment: @Ben Templates can be used for static polymorphism, which does not require virtual functions

Comment: @peoro there are some clever ways to use templates to perform a type of polymorphism without runtime vtable checks.  Very useful in situations where performance matters

Comment: @Foo: "Alignment is not an issue" -- true, but *only* if you don't specifically make it be one (with custom alignment requirements).

Comment: @Foo Bah: true, but that's a template, not a *polymorphic type*.  The standard says (section `[class.virtual]`): "A class that declares or
inherits a virtual function is called a *polymorphic class*."

Comment: @Foo Bah, I cutted out my comment about polymorphism after noticing that Ben Voigt commented it too. Anyway, static polymorphism is not polymorphism. It's a pattern used to _simulate_ what you would have with polymorphism. Static polymorphism is only done at compile time, when you know the most derived type of the objects, so they're not polymorphic (although templates make it look that way).

Answer (score 3):

Because `malloc` doesn't call the class's constructor, and doesn't know anything about any particular alignment requirements it might have. If you need to use `malloc` (not recommended), take a look at [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) (assuming you don't want to overload the regular `new` for some reason).

Comment: This doesn't answer any of my three questions. `malloc` doesn't call the constructor, but I used the assignment operator, with a correctly constructed object on that memory region, so why isn't that enough?

Comment: I'm not sure if the assignment operator performs any sanity checks (e.g. type checks?) on the assignee... if it does, then it won't work. What kind of access violation are you seeing -- read or write? And where exactly does it happen in the code?

Comment: @peoro: The preconditions on the assignment operator are that BOTH sides are properly constructed objects.

Comment: @Mehrdad: alignment is a red herring.  malloc aligns stuff properly.  The problem is that non-POD classes can't be used before construction.

Comment: @Ben: I meant if the alignment was *more* than `malloc`'s, not less (e.g. if a field was set to 64-byte alignment manually).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Nothing has more alignment than malloc.  peoro quoted the right section from the malloc description that covers this.

Comment: @Ben: And what if you need page-aligned data? You think `malloc` gives you that?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's possible for types _not in C++_ to have more alignment than malloc - malloc may not have alignment for SSE 128-bit loads/stores, for example - however you'd only notice this if you were using inline asm or intrinsics outside the scope of C++.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Objects don't require alignment that `malloc` doesn't give.  If your algorithm requires more alignment that's another story, but the object is still usable.

Comment: @bdonlan: No, you'd also easily notice it if you used `__declspec(align(32))` (MS VC).

Comment: @Ben: There was no clue in the post telling me where the access violation occurred. So it could very reasonably have been because of an alignment issue with one of the object's fields, assigning a bigger object to a smaller space in memory. Whether or not it's actually the reason behind this particular problem, it was a reasonable and completely correct answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Huh?  "Assigning a bigger object to a smaller space in memory" is not an *alignment* problem.

Comment: @Ben: Er, sorry, typo -- I meant to a space that has a smaller *alignment*. Nice catch.

Comment: @Mehrdad: More to the point, it's a red herring because `malloc` and `new` obey the same alignment rules.  From the standard: "allocation functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental alignment"

Comment: @Ben: So you're telling me that it's impossible to initialize a page-aligned object correctly with `new`, just as it is with a simple `malloc`? `new` is aware of the alignment; `malloc` isn't...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think you're talking about standard C++ here... C++0x will add support for "extended alignment" however.

Comment: @Ben: Just because `__declspec(align...)` or (its equivalent) isn't standard C++ doesn't mean it's not a valid potential situation... (are you claiming that just because, say, thread-local storage isn't standard, that people can't ask about it? or that it's not a potential problem/solution to their question?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Looking through the C++0x proposal, I conclude that `::operator new` and `malloc` both conform to the same alignment: the maximum fundamental alignment.  In order to meet the alignment requirements of an *over-aligned type* you therefore have to request enough additional space so that some subset of the space is properly aligned.

Comment: @Ben: I really don't see the point of your argument here... you're claiming my answer is invalid simply because it's not "standard C++". Sorry, but real-world people sometimes use compiler extensions in valid situations, and I don't see why you're making so much of an effort to prove me wrong about something like this, when my answer's valid (even if it's not standard).

Comment: @Ben: "Also, you can clearly see from the source code in the question that none of the classes require extended alignment." Really? No, I don't: "Of course my actual application is a lot more complex." And honestly, I'll just stop commenting if you won't... feel free to comment more here; vote it down if you'd like, but I don't feel like this is getting anywhere, not sure about you though.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because all of your focus on alignment affects placement `new` too.  Those non-standard compiler extensions don't just break `malloc`, but also `std::vector` and all the other standard library containers.

Comment: @Mehrdad, that may be the case, but using `new` won't help you here. I just ran a test, and even in MSVC++, `new` ignores `__declspec(align(n))` and aligns to an 8-byte multiple.

Comment: @Merhdad: Ok, good point about "actual code is more complex".  I withdraw my claim that there are necessarily no extended alignment restrictions in play.

Answer (score 2):

Classes with `virtual` members contain a pointer to a so-called vtable - basically a table of function pointers to the implementation of these virtual members. When you use `operator new`, the constructor is called, which, even if it is an implicit constructor, will set up this pointer to the vtable properly.

However, malloc does not call the constructor. The vtable pointer is left uninitialized, point to some random memory. When you then attempt to call a virtual function, you dereference a bad pointer and crash (undefined behavior).

The solution is to use placement new to initialize the object before using it:

```
int main( ) {
    Derived *d;
    d = (Derived*) malloc( sizeof(Derived) );
    new(d) Derived(123); // invoke constructor
// You could also do:
//    new(d) Derived;
//    *d = Derived( 123 );

    std::cout << d->x() << std::endl; // crash

    // Although in your case it does not matter, it's good to clean up after yourself by
    // calling the destructor
    d->~Derived();
    return 0;
}
```

Some important things to note:

- Alignment is not a problem. Memory from malloc is properly aligned for any C++ type.
- Assigning with `=` does not help. The default implementation of `=` copies all member variables, but the vtable pointer is not a member and is not copied.
- Construction is not required for POD types. Non-POD types may or may not require it (it's undefined behavior if you don't). In particular, the constructor also calls member variable constructors; so if you don't construct the outer object, inner objects may be broken as well.

Comment: All this v-table stuff is true in most implementations, but not required by the standard.  All the standard says is that objects with virtual members are non-POD, and therefore need to be initialized by executing the constructor.

Comment: Interesting, is it then the case that the vtable is never "reassigned"? it is built on construction but never touched by assignment or anything. (except perhaps placement new).

Answer (score 1):

I don't belive that the object's constructor is called when you use malloc.

Comment: I was under the impression that the new operator calls the constructor. MSDN and Wikipedia seem to agree. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the continued downvoting here.  alanp fixed the double negative in his answer, it is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

section `[basic.life]` of the standard says

> The lifetime of an object is a runtime property of the object. An object is said to have non-trivial initialization if  it  is  of  a  class  or  aggregate  type  and  it  or  one  of  its  members  is  initialized  by  a  constructor  other than a trivial default constructor.  [ Note: initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-trivial initialization.  — end note ] The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
> - if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.

Since your class has virtual members, it requires non-trivial initialization.  You can't assign an object whose lifetime hasn't started, you have to *initialize* it with `new`.