# Exception handled, but after being caught program is aborted

Tags: c++, exception, metaprogramming

I'm writing a C++ library based on expression templates (metaprogramming).

I have a `Matrix` class and I have implemented also a `SubMatrix` class to extract a part of a matrix. I have already set up the exception handling for the assignment `=` operator for the case an assignment has different operand sizes and I'm now setting up the exception handling for the sub-matrix extraction for the cases when the submatrix indices do not match the original matrix. I have verified that the exception handling for the assignment `=` works correctly.

The syntax of the `SubMatrix` extraction is the following

```
B=SubMatrix(A,a,b,c,d);
```

which has the following Matlab equivalent

```
B=A(a:b,c:d);
```

When I try

```
Matrix<double>      A_H(3,4);
Matrix<double>      B_H(3,2);
try { B_H = SubMatrix(A_H,0,1,1,2); } catch(exception &e) { cout << e.what() << endl; return; }
```

the correct exception of the `SubMatrix` is caught, but the program is aborted immediately afterwards. I have verified that the correct exception is caught by brutally freezing the video output by adding a `getch();` to `try-catch`, namely

```
try { B_H = SubMatrix(A_H,0,1,1,2); } catch(exception &e) { cout << e.what() << endl; getch(); return; }
```

Anyone has an explanation? Is there any "interference" between the exception handling of the `SubMatrix` and that of the assignment `=`? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT - FUNCTION WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS CAUGHT**

```
template<class T> 
Expr<SubMatrixExpr<const T*,T>,T> SubMatrix(const Matrix<T>&v,const int a,const int b,const int c,const int d) 
{   if((a >= 0) && (a < v.GetRows()) && (a <= b) && (b >= 0) && (b < v.GetRows()) && 
       (c >= 0) && (c < v.GetColumns()) && (c <= d) && (d >= 0) && (d < v.GetColumns())) 
    { 
        typedef SubMatrixExpr<const T*,T> SExpr; 
        return Expr<SExpr,T>(SExpr(v.GetDataPointer(),v.GetRows(),v.GetColumns(),a,b,c,d),b-a+1,d-c+1); 
    } else {    char* str0 = "************************************\n"; 
                char* str1 = "* CPU SubMatrix indices must match *\n"; 
                char* str2 = "Matrix size: "; 
                char* str3 = "SubMatrix indices (a,b,c,d): "; 
                char* catString = (char*) malloc(2*strlen(str0)+strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+strlen(str3)+50*sizeof(char)); 
                sprintf(catString, "%s%s%s\n%s%i x %i\n%s(%i,%i,%i,%i)\n",str0,str1,str0,str2,v.GetRows(),v.GetColumns(),str3,a,b,c,d); 
                throw  GenericError(catString,__FILE__,__LINE__); 
            } 
}
```

**EDIT - EXCEPTION HANDLING CLASSES**

```
#define Error_msg_1 "Error in file"
#define Double_new_line "\n\n"
#define Error_msg_2 "on line"

class LibraryException: public std::exception
{
    private:
        const char *message_;
        const char *file_;
        int line_;
    protected:
        LibraryException(const char *message, const char* file, int line): message_(message), file_(file), line_(line) {}
    public:
        int get_line() const { return line_; }
        const char* get_file() const { return file_; }
        virtual const char* what() const throw() 
        {
            char buf[20];
            sprintf(buf, "%d", line_);

            char* catString = (char*) malloc(strlen(Error_msg_1)+strlen(Double_new_line)+strlen(file_)+strlen(Double_new_line)+strlen(Error_msg_2)+strlen(buf)+strlen(message_));
            sprintf(catString, "%s \n\n%s\n\n%s %s\n\n%s", Error_msg_1,file_,Error_msg_2,buf,message_);
            return catString; }
};

class GenericError: public LibraryException
{
public:
    GenericError(const char *message, const char* file, int line) :
    LibraryException(message, file, line) {}
};
```

**EDIT - MALLOC AND VIRTUAL FUNCTIONS**

From the post [What exactly is the problem with malloc() and virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311548/what-exactly-is-the-problem-with-malloc-and-virtual-functions), it emerges that there are problems in using `malloc` in virtual functions. Anyway, I have tried also using `new`, but the problem remains and I have checked that I could not dynamically allocate anything within the `virtual` function. Furthermore, this problem is "intermittent", sometimes it happens and sometimes not. Finally, I have solved the problem with a static allocation like this

```
        virtual const char* what() const throw() 
        {
            char buf[20];
            sprintf(buf, "%d", line_);

            char catString[2048];
            sprintf(catString, "%s \n\n%s\n\n%s %s\n\n%s", Error_msg_1,file_,Error_msg_2,buf,message_);
            return &catString[0]; }
        };
```

Comment: Can you provide code for whole function?

Comment: Do you mean the `SubMatrix` class or the `Exception` class or else?

Comment: I mean whole function where error is being handled. Not just part whith try/catch

Comment: Edited the post with the function where the exception is caught.

Comment: There is only throw here, and you don't need all of this \ in templates.

Comment: I apologize. I removed all the unnecessary \. My function was actually defined as a macro. What other information do you need?

Comment: I don't see any try/catch in function you have provided, only single throw

Comment: There is none. The only `try-catch` I'm using is for trying `B_H = SubMatrix(A_H,0,1,1,2);`, as in the original post.

Comment: And I was asking about code around that. try/catch

Comment: Added in my newly edited post.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* catString = (char*) malloc(strlen(Error_msg_1)+strlen(Double_new_line)+strlen(file_)+strlen(Double_new_line)+strlen(Error_msg_2)+strlen(buf)+strlen(message_));
```

There is not enough memory allocated here, since format string in addition to all strings conatins spaces \ns and terminal zero. While Double_new_line being counted for \n\n spaces and terminal zero still remains.
Also why using `malloc` and not `new`? Or even better `std::string`? Since I don't see any free this will lead to memory leak.

Comment: I have verified that, unfortunately, this is not the reason of my issue. I will check better and provide a further comment, if I will have one.

Comment: Concerning the memory leak, the `catString` memory is allocated only once an exception is found and after that the program is terminated. Is it really an issue?